# User removal from TFS2013

Tags: tfs

Is there any way to completely remove an user from a TFS2013 server (even from project valid users list).

I've a developer who is part of different collections/projects (around 50) and it's hard to remove them from each and every collection/project. Also if I go and remove manually I'm not sure how accurate it will be. They are moved to a different project and are not using TFS anymore. I want to remove him completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user with access to Team Foundation Server (TFS) leaves a company, an administrator would typically remove them from Azure Active Directory or Active Directory. This will automatically void their user account and remove their ability to access or connect to TFS.

In your case to remove an obsolete account from TFS, usually need to **delete the user from all groups/collection they belonged to**. You could remove it from Global Security dialog in security of team project collection. In the Users and groups list, click the user whom you want to remove, and click Remove.

For multiple collection/groups, you could also use [tfssecurity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/command-line/tfssecurity-cmd)  command.

*Use `tfssecurity /i` command to list users belongs to which groups*

```
 tfssecurity /i "domain\account" /server:http://serverName:8080/tfs
```

*And using `tfssecurity /g-` command to remove that user from a group*

```
tfssecurity /g- "[TeamProject1]\Contributors" n:domain\account /collection:http://serverName:8080/tfs/Collection
```

Another solution could be using this 3-party software--[Team Foundation Server Administration Tool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2013/12/15/announcing-team-foundation-server-administration-tool/) it works with tfs 2013.

---

Moreover, changes you make to local or Active Directory groups do not get reflected in TFS immediately. Instead, TFS will synchronize those groups regularly.

A periodic clean-up job that is executed removes people from the global groups. If you just wait, they will disappear in a couple of days. They will not have access to any of the TFS assets however.

Well, you could also kick it off: [Force TFS to sync with Active Directory](https://blogs.msmvps.com/vstsblog/2011/02/17/force-tfs-to-sync-with-active-directory/)